# Hyperref package and color - can I choose a dark green for citecolor?

Tags: hyperref, color

Using the Hyperref and color links, I find that the Green color for the citecolor is very pale when printed on a B/W printer. 
Can I darken the Green color and how can I do this, please?
I would sincerely appreciate help in this.
Many thanks

Comment: You can change it to any color: `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[%  
  citecolor=Green]%
{hyperref}`. But if you use B/W printer, better don't use colors at all.

Answer (score 3):

This colors the reference, not the frame:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  citecolor=SpringGreen4
}

\begin{document}
\cite{Lam94}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

[image]